# Is it possible to get patch to patch files in $HOME and system both in one command and file?

Tags: patch

I have created the following patch file using `diff -u file1 file2 | file.patch` and then edited out the `---` line and changed the path:

ArkOS_Dev_Openbox.patch

```
+++ ~/.config/openbox/menu.xml  2016-07-28 21:21:55.683952870 +0200
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@
 <item label="Terminal"><action name="Execute"><execute>lxterminal</execute></action></item>
 <item label="Browser"><action name="Execute"><execute>firefox</execute></action></item>
 <item label="File Manager"><action name="Execute"><execute>spacefm</execute></action></item>
-<item label="Editor"><action name="Execute"><execute>geany</execute></action></item>
+<item label="Editor"><action name="Execute"><execute>gksu geany</execute></action></item>

 <separator/>
 <menu id="applications" label="Applications" execute="xdg_menu --format openbox3-pipe --root-menu /etc/xdg/menus/arch-applications.menu" />

+++ /usr/share/applications/geany.desktop.bak   2016-07-29 22:43:43.483359679 +0200
@@ -130,7 +130,7 @@
 Comment[vi]=Một IDE nhanh và nhẹ nhàng dùng GTK+
 Comment[zh_CN]=GTK+ 编写的轻快的 IDE
 Comment[zh_TW]=一個快速且輕巧的 GTK+ 整合開發環境
-Exec=geany %F
+Exec=gksu geany %F
 Icon=geany
 Terminal=false
 Categories=GTK;Development;IDE;
```

And I try to run this patch with the following command.

`sudo patch -d / -p0 < ArkOS_Dev_Openbox.patch`

This results in the first file not being found due to the tilde. I've tried using $HOME as well to no avail.

I think I'm trying to use patches in a way what I think they're not meant for, a desktop environment instead of a package.

So my question is, can I use patches this way? 
Should I use patches this way? 
If so how?
If not what should I use instead?

Comment: How did you create the patch? Did you get `diff` to output the first path with a tilde? (I also assume you mean `$HOME` and not `$Home`)

Comment: `diff` output, took out the `---` line and added a pathname, and also copy pasted the contents of the next patch into the first one. This works with the command above if I only need to patch system files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check of the [sources](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/patch.git) shows that GNU patch for instance does not expand tilde into home-directories.  Likely none of the other implementations do, since most —all but ***perhaps*** some closed-source Unix versions — are based on earlier versions of GNU patch (as it evolved from Larry Wall's original).

You could handle this by a sed-script, e.g., something like this:

```
sed -e "s,~/,$HOME/," ArkOS_Dev_Openbox.patch | sudo patch -d / -p0
```

Further reading:

- [patch](http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/diffstat.html#dep_patch) (background information for diffstat)
- [patch](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/patch.html) (POSIX)